# Change Wordpress URL from example.com/wordpress to example.com/blog

Tags: wordpress

It seems like an issue that has been talked about a large number of times, but for some reason, I can't seem to get it to work.

Goal:  Change Wordpress site from example.com/wordpress to example.com/blog

Here is what I've tried:

1. Changed the Wordpress root folder from "wordpress" to "blog"
2. Then, in phpmyAdmin, changed the siteurl and home url's to example.com/blog

When that did not work, I also went into my theme's functions.php file and added:

```
update_option('siteurl','http://example.com/blog');
update_option('home','http://example.com/blog');
```

immediately after the opening

```
<?php
```

tag.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean exactly?  Are you not getting anything at example.com/blog? Or are you seeing a 'broken' version of your site (no stylesheet, scripts etc)?

Comment: Please read the comments under Philippe Boissonneault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update all URLs in your database too.

Take a look at this script:
http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: Are you saying that my changes to that database via phpmyAdmin is not sufficient?

Comment: If you changed urls in serialized strings, it will not work. because you'll need to reserialize them to get the appropriate number of characters of the string. That's why scripts like the one above exists.

Comment: Ok, I installed the script, renamed it, and I find the same issue as before.  Warning: require_once(/home/kokorugs/public_html/wordpress/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/kokorugs/public_html/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php on line 12

Comment: I have also changed my root folder from "wordpress" to "blog" and when I change it back to wordpress, I am able to load my site, but the theme is not working properly.

Comment: I reversed the script and back to the drawing board.

Comment: If you move everything from `/wordpress/` to `/blog/` there shouldn't be anything loading `/wordpress/*` files so I don't understand.

Comment: What I did was this:  First, upload script, run script to find and replace http://example.com/wordpress to http://example.com/blog.  13 entries where changed.  I loaded my site at example.com/wordpress and found the theme files were not loaded, and the admin was unaccessible.  Then I tried changing the wordpress root folder to "blog" and then nothing loaded. 404 errors for site and admin like you would think would happen.  Changed back the folder from blog to wordpress, and ran the script once again with the opposite search and replace.  Now everything is the same as it started.

Comment: Also, after running the script, and before and after changing the root folder, I tried example.com/blog and received 404 errors both times.

Comment: Wordpress should be "simple" to move from a folder to another. Step1: rename your folder, Step2: run the script, **Step3**: you need to update the `.htaccess` file to your new folder, Step4: Go to new URL

Comment: Okay, it seems step three is my problem. I haven't touched my .htaccess file.  I will search how best to do that.

Comment: Would you happen to know where the .htaccess file is located?

Comment: root directory (it may be hidden)

Comment: Of wordpress, or my entire sites root directory?

Comment: Found two, one says deny all. The other only contains this:

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all

<FilesMatch "^akismet\.(css|js)$">
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

Comment: It is hard to believe that the htaccess file is causing the problems.

Comment: htaccess may be causing your 404 error because the `/wordpress/` directory is defined for redirection. Change every `/wordpress/` into `/blog/`

Comment: What I ended up doing is just uninstalled wordpress and reinstalling to the blog directory and it works great.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

When your domain name or URLs change - i.e. from http://example.com/blog to http://example.com, or http://example.com to http://example.net - there are additional concerns. The files and database can be moved, however references to the old domain name or location will remain in the database, and that can cause issues with links or theme display.

If you do a search and replace on your entire database to change the URLs, you can cause issues with data serialization, due to the fact that some themes and widgets store values with the length of your URL marked. When this changes, things break. To avoid that serialization issue, you have two options:

1- Only perform a search and replace on the wp_posts table.

2- Use the Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script to safely change all instances. ( If you are a developer, use this option. It is a one step process as opposed to the 15-step procedure below )

Info taken from http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script: http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 1):

You could try this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

From its own description:
"Exports your database, does a find and replace on URLs and file paths, then allows you to save it to your computer."

Comment: This seems to do the same thing as the script posted earlier. I used the script, changed all the urls and received a fatal error on my site. So, I reversed the script, and now everything is back to normal.  However, I have no idea why it does not work.